# How to clean the memory properly (conceptual, SWIFT)

Tags: swift, memory, didreceivememorywarning

I have a loop where I add objects (.append) to an array and remove them after a while in a Background-Task (dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {)
During this loop my array has theoretically a max amount of objects in it, because I am removing old objects.

What I observe is, that the memory cunsumption goes high (over 400MB) till I get a didReceiveMemoryWarning Warning and my didReceiveMemoryWarning is called and sometimes the app just crashes. So it looks like my cleaning doesn't work, BUT
When stopping in the middle of the loop and waiting for some seconds (say 10 seconds) I see the memory slowly going down to my expected value (60MB).

So I guess I conceptually doing this wrong.

How to do this properly ? Is there a way to force cleaning memory like in Java forcegc ?

When cleaning the objects in the main task (dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{) the memory doesn't reach the limit, but the GUI is stocking.

Comment: Not sure, why you not just get rid of the array when you are finished with it. But anyway, one possible issue is that your code is not correct regarding concurrency - for example: the code where you add objects executes on a different queue than the code that removes these objects (unless, both queues have the same parent queue). Please add more info and code.